# Nothing drawn when drawing in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, paintcomponent

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in the JPanel however it wont show up, It works in the frame however.

if you uncomment //frame.getContentPane().add(rect); //Will draw if its in the frame
    and comment     frame.getContentPane().add(panel); // but not in the panel
      the rectangle will draw.

Thanks for the help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingRect{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingRect d = new DrawingRect();
    }

  public DrawingRect(){

     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing a rect");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (500,500));

     Rect rect = new Rect();

     JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (500,500));
     panel.setVisible(true);

     panel.add(rect);

    //frame.getContentPane().add(rect); //Will draw if its in the frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel); // but not in the panel


     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);  



     panel.repaint();
     frame.repaint();



  }

  public class Rect extends JComponent{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRoundRect(10, 10, 100, 100, 20, 20);  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try putting it in `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, also maybe not try to do everything in the constructor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Rect is drawing fine, but it's very very small! To see what I mean, show it's size after it has been rendered:

```
  Rect rect = new Rect();
  rect.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("rect"));

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
  panel.setVisible(true);

  panel.add(rect);

  // frame.getContentPane().add(rect); //Will draw if its in the frame
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel); // but not in the panel

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);

  System.out.println(rect.getSize());
```

You'll get something like:

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=1,height=1]
```

Meaning it is just 1 pixel by 1 pixel -- too small to see.

The solution is to use proper layouts and give it a preferred size so that it will show. e.g.,

```
   public class Rect extends JComponent {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private static final int PREF_W = 150;
      private static final int PREF_H = 150;

      @Override
      // public void paint(Graphics g) {
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.drawRoundRect(10, 10, 100, 100, 20, 20);
      }

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
      }
   }
```

Also, draw with the JComponent's paintComponent method, not its paint method.

Comment: I was just about to post this, beat me to it. +1

Comment: thank you! :) its only a tiny part of my dissertation but you saved me a lot of time/trouble/sleep .. ect

Comment: Ive sort of hit a snag here again, my plan was to draw multiple rectangles (objects of data structure), and I thought that I would just set the x and y in the draw method in the Rect class to position it however they get added to the JPanel in the flowLayout or whatever its useing .. what is the best way to draw multiple Rects to acheive something like this.   http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C201/html/ch4-2.jpg

Comment: I've used two rects and got them draw over lapping as expected using .. swingPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
  rect1.setBounds(40, 50, 110, 110);
  rect.setBounds(50, 50, 110, 110); Is that a bit of a hack of is that acceptable

Comment: @Andy: Consider creating an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` and in the paintComponent method, use a for loop to iterate through the list drawing each Rectangle.